# What is a good Javascript RDFa parser implementation?

Tags: javascript, parsing, rdfa, fresnel

I am looking to implement a client side RDFa based formatting for a web application.  This would be similar to [Mark Birbeck's](http://webbackplane.com/mark-birbeck) [ubiquity-rdfa](http://code.google.com/p/ubiquity-rdfa/) project.

Mark's project looks fantastic but it has at least two drawbacks:

1. It is slow.  Adding RDFa formatting to a [simple page](http://ubiquity-rdfa.googlecode.com/svn/branches/0.7/test/tutorial-step-2.html) causes a noticeable delay in page loading.
2. It is complex.  The ubiquity-rdfa project makes use of the [w3c fresnel specification](http://www.w3.org/2005/04/fresnel-info/) which is complex way to add simple annotations to client markup.

I am looking for a lighter weight way of adding annotations through client code and I don't mind doing some work to get it.

What I would like is a fast and reliable Javascript RDFa parser.

Some implementations that I have found include:

- [W3C RDFa bookmarklet parser](http://www.w3.org/2006/07/SWD/RDFa/impl/js/)
- [Elias Torres RDFa extractor](http://torrez.us/rdfa/)

I am interested to know if you would recommend one of these, or another, RDFa Javascript implementation.

Thanks!

Comment: See also [W3C Comparison of RDFJS libraries](https://www.w3.org/community/rdfjs/wiki/Comparison_of_RDFJS_libraries)

Answer (score 4):

I had good experiences with the RDfa parser in [rdfQuery](http://code.google.com/p/rdfquery/). Source code is [here](http://code.google.com/p/rdfquery/source/browse/trunk/jquery.rdfa.js).

Answer (score 2):

[VIE](http://viejs.org) contains a reasonably simple RDFa parser and writer. RDFa entities on a page become accessible as [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) models and collections. Writing RDFa happens via updating Backbone model contents, which triggers a `render` action on a View.

In this case the RDFa parsing happens with jQuery.

VIE source code is available in github.com/bergie/VIE